# GTest with Eclipse CDT - Functions could not be resolved after adding library

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, eclipse-cdt, googletest

I am having an issue getting the Google Test Framework to work in Eclipse CDT, running on Fedora 18.

- fuse_gtest_files.py was used to create the gtest.h and gtest-all.cc files in a separate directory (gtest_lib), which was added to the project and excluded from Release/Debug builds
- A new build configuration (UnitTests) was made and the .cpp with main() from my src file was excluded
- A folder (test) was made to hold my unit test and .cpp with the gtest main(), also excluded from Release/Debug builds
- The include path (-l) for the GCC Compiler was updated to include the workspace folder gtest_lib, for both the test and gtest_lib folders.  The test folder also includes the src folder.
- The library for pthread was added to the GCC Compiler.

Eclipse is now showing that it is able to locate the header gtest/gtest.h, but all the functions that should be contained in gtest-all.cc are coming up as "Could not be resolved".  Mainly the InitGoogleTest and RUN_ALL_TEST().  Any suggestions?